# Sequelize,findAll, attributes can not rename column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My Table data:

> Mytable(id,col1,col2,time)

with data

> Mytable("1","val1","val2","time")

I fetch data by this code:

```
async function getData() {
   const mytables = await Mytable.findAll(
     { where: { id: othervalue }},
     { attributes: ['col1',['id', 'newnameid'],'newnamecol1']}
   );
   console.log(JSON.stringifty(mytables));
}
getData();
```

I want data only like this:

> [ {'newnameid':'1','newnamecol1':'val1'} ]

But I got this:

> [ {'id':'1','col1':'val1','col2':'val2,'time':'time''} ]

Uhm, what is possible wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use findAll and

```
      const convertedData = await rows.map(arrObj => {
      return {
        newname: reqbody.olddata
      }})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async function getData() {
   const mytables = await Mytable.findAll(
     { 
         where: { id: othervalue },
         attributes: ['col1',['id', 'newnameid'],'newnamecol1']
     },

   );
   console.log(JSON.stringifty(mytables));
}
getData();
```

**Updated:**
`attributes: ['col1',['id', 'newnameid'],'newnamecol1']` -> inside first `{}`

Comment: code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'newnamecol1' in 'field list'",
    sql: "SELECT `col1`, `id` AS `newnameid`, `newnamecol1` FROM `mytable` AS `mytable` WHERE `mytable`.`id` = 'othervalue';",
    parameters: undefined